# Flyway in Kotlin Gradle - cannot import FlywayMigrateTask

Tags: kotlin, gradle, database-migration, flyway, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to run two different flyway migrations on two different shcemas, each with their own user account.
According to the Flyway documentation I only need to set up one custom task for each connection with `FlywayMigrateTask`. From official documentation using default (Groovy) gradle:

```
task migrateDatabase1(type: org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:mydb1'
    user = 'myUsr1'
    password = 'mySecretPwd1'
}

task migrateDatabase2(type: org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:mydb2'
    user = 'myUsr2'
    password = 'mySecretPwd2'
}
```

I try to do this in Kotlin gradle (kts) but my project can't resolve the refrence to `FlywayMigrateTask`, even though I have it in my `External Libraties`:

[image]

How I register task:

```
tasks.register(
    "flywayTesting", 
    type = org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask::class.java) {
    // Details hidden
}
```

I'm able to resolve `org.flywaydb.gradle.task` package but not the `FlywayMigrateTask` class in the task folder.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Highligts from my gradle setup:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.0"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "8.5.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<Wrapper> {
    gradleVersion = "6.8.2"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.1")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:8.5.0")
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets["main"].apply {
        kotlin.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you run `./gradlew flywayTesting` from the command line? Do you see any errors, except for in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.

Add the Flyway Gradle plugin first:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "9.22.0"
}
```

Then, define a custom task:

```kotlin
task("flywayMigrateLocal", org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask::class) {
    description = "Migrates the local database"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
    user = "test"
    password = "test"
    locations = arrayOf(
        "filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration",
        "filesystem:src/test/resources/flyway/migrations_local"
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
task<org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask>("migrateDatabase1") {
url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:mydb1'
    user = 'myUsr1'
    password = 'mySecretPwd1'
}

task<org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask>("migrateDatabase2") {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:mydb2'
    user = 'myUsr2'
    password = 'mySecretPwd2'
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question.